# Is Lojack preinstalled on Dell's laptops?

Tags: laptop, bloatware

I'm looking at buying a Dell Studio 15 or similar. Unfortunately, they all seem to come with Lojack software included and no option to take it out of the build.

I really do not want this software installed on my laptop. It sounds really abusable, and hard to get rid of once installed - it hides in your BIOS and survives reinstalls, etc.

Does anyone know whether Lojack comes preinstalled on this machine, or if they just ship you a disc, which could subsequently be broken in half and/or microwaved into submission?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can [ask them](http://www.freakyacres.com/remove_computrace_lojack) to remove LoJack from your machine once you have it. You just need to send them proof that you actually own the machine...

Answer (score 1):

The article [How to remove Computrace Lojack](http://www.freakyacres.com/remove_computrace_lojack) describes how Lojack is imprinted into the BIOS of the computer.

There are therefore two methods described in the article for stopping it.

First is to install a new BIOS, with is highly risky for the health of your computer.

Second method is:

1. End the process called rpcnetp.exe
   or rpcnet.exe
2. In `C:\Windows\System32` delete
   rpcnetp.exe, rpcnet.exe,
   rpcnetp.dll, rpcnet.dll etc.
3. Create new text files of the same
   name as the deleted files.
4. Set these files to be read only.
5. Reboot and check that the Lojack files have not returned.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what their policies are today, but the Dell laptop I ordered a little over two years ago included Lojack on a separate CD rather than pre-installed.